# How to fix SQLNonTransientConnectionException in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect my java program to a MySql database through Wamp, and all I get is plethora of SQL Exceptions.

I have tried nearly every question or queries or answers available on Stackoverflow, but none of the answers solved my issue....

Maybe my question will be marked duplicate but i have no idea why solutions mentioned in other answers aren't working for me despite getting hundred's of upvotes.

Here is my code

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLTest{
    private static Connection connect = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Trying to Establish Database Connection.....");
            //connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/sys?user=root&password=root&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/sys", "root", "root");
            System.out.println("Connection Established.");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("connection problem");
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Some Other Problem.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what i get in return

[image: The output of program]

Comment: Include the whole stacktrace in your question. The exception name alone is quite useless.

Comment: Your MySQL server is probably not listening on port 8080. That's likely the port that Apache (web server) is listening on. Try connecting to port 3306 instead.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks a ton it worked. The default port in httpd.conf file was set to 8080. I dont know somehow 3306 works. though not needed but if anyone can explain **why is this working** that would great.

Comment: If you're asking why it's 3306, the answer is that it's just convention. MySQL goes through port 3306, Postgre is 5432, etc. To explain why switching ports solved your issue, think of the data as mail getting sent to the wrong address. You fixed the address, and your letters are making it to their correct destination now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default port in httpd.conf file was set to 8080. I dont know somehow 3306 works.

The WAMP stack consists of four components: Windows, Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

Apache is the server software that receives HTTP requests and returns web pages. `httpd.conf` is its configuration file. The default port for Apache is 80, but WAMP stacks usually use a different port like 8080 for development purposes.

MySQL is the component that receives SQL queries and returns the results from those queries. It listens on a different port than Apache. The configuration file for MySQL is `my.ini`. The default port for MySQL is 3306.